# how to fixalignment of kendo when we add a new item which exceeds the width of kendo multiselect

Tags: kendo-ui

I am adding new item in kendo multiselect dropdown which is a very big text.On typing that text it goes on making the width of kendo wider.I want the kendo width to be fixed and the cursor should be positioned next to the new skill after the skill is added.Please suggest a solution.

CODE:

```
$("#selects").kendoMultiSelect({ 
  placeholder: "Skills", 
  dataTextField: 'text', 
  dataValueField: 'value', 
  dataSource: data, 
  dataBound: onDataBound, 
  filtering: onFiltering, 
  deselect: onDeselect, 
  select: onSelect, 
  change: onChange, 
  close: onClose, 
  open: onOpen, 
  filter: "startswith" 
});
```

Comment: Please show us your code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: try adding a new big text to kendo multiselect dropdown which cannot be selected from dropdown as an item ,if we go on typing that text more than the width of kendo multiselect the kendo multiselect increases its width as long as we type.code

Comment: code-$(\"#selects\").kendoMultiSelect({
              placeholder: \"Skills\",
                dataTextField: 'text',
                dataValueField: 'value',
                dataSource: data, 
                dataBound: onDataBound,
                filtering: onFiltering,
                deselect: onDeselect,
                select: onSelect,
                change: onChange,
                close: onClose,
                open: onOpen,
                filter: \"startswith\"         
                 
            });

Comment: Please mark this question as closed.I found the solution.

Comment: You should post your solution for future searchers and then mark that solution as accepted.